# why chrome.exe and svchost.exe connecting to RDP port 3389 on 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, rdp, eventviewer

i noticed in the event viewer that chrome.exe and svchost.exe are connecting to 127.0.0.1 remotely using RDP port 3389 on multiple Pc's . i couldn't figure out why this event happens even though that none of the employee is using chrome remote desktop application and i couldn't replicate this scenario on my own pc does anyone have similar issue?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcykd.png)

Comment: attached pics here
https://imgur.com/a/jaGsGon
https://imgur.com/Pr0drut
https://imgur.com/GYkbR2E

Answer (score 0):

I have no reputation to comment so I post as an answer. Some of sites are known to perform a port scan of localhost:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232345/ebay-web-site-tries-to-connect-to-wss-localhostxxxxx-is-this-legit-or-they

Comment: Hi vkip, and welcome to the community. The link you posted is right on target but in order to make your contribution more useful it is always a good practice to expand or summarise the content of the external resources. Could you edit your answer to add some more context?